# Vibe.d - Can not generate JS script for rest api

Tags: javascript, rest, d, vibed

I'm trying to generate JS for my simple REST API like eg described here: [doc](http://dpldocs.info/experimental-docs/vibe.web.rest.generateRestJSClient.html). My example code:

```
import vibe.d;
import wbapi;
import std.array : appender;
import vibe.core.file;

void main()
{
  // generate JS for access
  auto test = appender!string;
  auto settingsJS = new RestInterfaceSettings;

  settingsJS.baseURL = URL("http://localhost/api/integration/");
  generateRestJSClient!IfWhiteBlowerAPI(test, settingsJS);
}
```

and interface:

```
    @path("/api/integration")
    interface IfWhiteBlowerAPI
    {
        Json get();
        string postDeaf(Json obj);
    }
```

Everything is compiling without any problem but i can't find generated JS anywhere. Am i looking in wrong place - main tree of app project?

Comment: Have you run the resulting executable? The generation would happen at runtime (D's CTFE can't write to the filesystem).

Comment: Yes, im building it with dub and it is automatically run after build. I try to start it manually too, but with same effect.. no js file.

Answer (score 0):

I get help on vibed IRC channel. There is [appender](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_array.html#Appender) which is "handling" generated JS data. After we generate it we need to save it to file manually, below working example:

```
import vibe.d;
import std.stdio;
import std.array : appender;
import vibe.core.file;

@path("/api/integration")
interface IfWhiteBlowerAPI
{
    Json get();
    string postDeaf(Json obj);
}

void main()
{
  // generate JS for access
  auto test = appender!string;
  auto settingsJS = new RestInterfaceSettings;

  settingsJS.baseURL = URL("http://localhost/api/integration/");
  generateRestJSClient!IfWhiteBlowerAPI(test, settingsJS);

  auto f = File("test.js", "w");
  f.write(test.data);
  f.close();
}
```